# Date conversion issue in java datatype

Tags: java

I have a string type date. I want to change it firstly into date datatype. But it is not formating date properly as I want.Here is my code

```
String a="12/11/2010";

        Date d=new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat as=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        d=as.parse(a);
  System.out.println(a);
```

Output is like this `:Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2012`

But I want output like this `12-10-2014` in Date data type, not in String data type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the default timezone in java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337557/what-is-the-default-timezone-in-java-util-date)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(as.format(d));
```

You should use your dateformatter object to format your date d.

If you want to parse it as 12/11/2010 and output as 12-11-2010 you could have 2 different dateformatters one for parse and one for output.  Ex.

```
    String a="12/11/2010";

    Date d=new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat as=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat as1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    d = as.parse(a);
    System.out.println(as1.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` is an instant in time, and although it has a `toString()` that is not replaceable. Instead you use a `DateFormat` (like the one you have) to `format` the output

```
String a="12/11/2010";
SimpleDateFormat as=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
Date d=as.parse(a);
System.out.println(as.format(d));
```