# Why does PySpark remove the timestamp offset?

Tags: time, pyspark

I am trying to parse dates in the Paris timezone (+2 UTC), and PySpark removes the offset when converting from string to timestamp:

```
df_times = spark.createDataFrame([('2020-12-31T06:53:21.000+02:00',)], ["t"])
# df_times:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
#    t:string
df_timestamp = df_times.select(F.to_timestamp(F.col("t")).alias('to_timestamp'))
# df_timestamp:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
#    to_timestamp:timestamp
df_timestamp.show()

+-------------------+
|       to_timestamp|
+-------------------+
|2020-12-31 04:53:21|
+-------------------+
```

Why doesn't PySpark display `2020-12-31 04:53:21` instead of `2020-12-31 06:53:21+02:00`?

It's especially frustrating when I try to retrieve the hour:

```
df_timestamp.select(F.hour("to_timestamp")).show()

+------------------+
|hour(to_timestamp)|
+------------------+
|                 4|
+------------------+
```

I don't want to display "4" hours, I want "6" as the hours.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code of [TimestampType](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4cb1cd6ab7b7bffd045a786b0ddb7c7783afdf46/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/TimestampType.scala#L36):

> Internally, a timestamp is stored as the number of microseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z (UTC+00:00)

This means spark does not store the information which the original timezone of the timestamp was but stores the timestamp in UTC. When printing a timestamp, the [default timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11337557/2129801) of the currently used JVM is used to *format* the output.

You can set the timezone by setting `spark.sql.session.timeZone`:

```python
print(spark.conf.get("spark.sql.session.timeZone"))
```

prints for me

```
Europe/Berlin
```

and thus

```python
df_timestamp.show()
```

gives for me

```
+-------------------+                                                           
|       to_timestamp|
+-------------------+
|2020-12-31 05:53:21|
+-------------------+
```

because in December the timezone for Berlin is `UTC+1`.

If I change the timezone to `UTC+2` I get a different result for the same dataframe:

```python
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC+2")
df_timestamp.show()
```

prints

```
df_timestamp.show()
+-------------------+
|       to_timestamp|
+-------------------+
|2020-12-31 06:53:21|
+-------------------+
```

The result of `hour` also depends on the configured timezone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it does not work in my notebook. I tried `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "France/Paris")` and 'UTC+2' but it does not change the output

Comment: @BeChillerToo which Spark version are you using? I think the time zone configuration has been [introduced in 2.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18936).

Comment: This strategy by Spark presupposes that I always care about the time in MY timezone.  I am trying to analyze data according to the users (source) time and that is impossible the way Spark does it (because it discards the original timezone offset).  In my case I strip off the timezone offset to prevent this conversion.

Comment: @absmiths internally Spark stores all timestamps in UTC, so no data is lost. You could try to store the "original" timezone as additional column