# C# Ticks convert to java util date; date is 5 hours behind why?

Tags: java, c#, date

I need help. I have been trying to figure out why java util date is 5 hours behind after converting from `C#` ticks.

in `C#`, the date is 6/8/2013 11:02:07 AM, I convert this date into ticks then pass it to java as `long`.

code snippet:

taken:

```
- long TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000L;
- long TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND = 10000;

java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date((ctime - TICKS_AT_EPOCH) / TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND);
```

Now java util date is Sat Jun 08 06:02:07 CDT 2013

Notice that the hour is 5 hours difference.

Any suggestions why?

Comment: I am still confused. I read the date from SQL database (server is in Central time) in C# application and assign it to C# DateTime object. It displays the correct date and time in C# application but I am not sure what timezone the DateTime is set to. How do I find this out?

Comment: This is what C# application display for the date: Jun Sat 8 11:02 2013 -05:00

Answer (score 5):

You are constructing a `java.util.Date` based on milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC.  You appear to be correcting from the fact that .net's `System.DateTime.Ticks` are based on 1/1/0001 and are 10,000 ticks to a millisecond.  That is correct, but you have forgotten to adjust to UTC.

In .Net, the value coming from `DateTime.Ticks` is highly dependent on the `DateTime.Kind` property.  There are three possible kinds of `DateTime` values.

- `DateTimeKind.Utc` - This kind means that the value represents UTC time.  It usually comes from a call to `DateTime.UtcNow`, but can also be constructed directly, and often is.  For example, you might be retrieving UTC times from a database.  You can feed the ticks from here directly into your conversion, and it will work.
- `DateTimeKind.Local` - This usually comes from a call to `DateTime.Now`.  The values are representative of the local time zone.  You will need to convert to UTC before checking the ticks.  You can do the following:

  ```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
  int utcTicks = dt.ToUniversalTime().Ticks;
  ```

  Be aware that if the time happens during a daylight saving "fall-back" style transition, the result might be incorrect.  The `DateTime` class has no idea about time zones.  It just reflects the current local clock.  If the value in `dt` is ambiguous, `ToUniversalTime()` will assume that the value is representative of *standard time*, even if you just retrieved it while in *daylight time*.  This is just one of the many confusing and probablematic aspects of `DateTime` in .net.
- `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` - This is the most common kind of `DateTime` you will encounter, and usually comes from `DateTime.Parse()` or a constructor like `new DateTime(...)`.  Unfortunately, there is nothing in here that will tell you about the time zone these dates are representative of.  You can still try calling `.ToUniversalTime()`, but the framework will make the assumption that these times are representative of your local time zone, as if the kind was `Local`.  That assumption could be completely wrong, depending on how you sourced the data.  There really is no safe way to transform an `Unspecified` `DateTime` to a UTC value (ticks or otherwise).

There are some solutions, such as using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`, or using the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library instead of the built-in types.  You can read more about these problems [here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now) and [here](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html).

Answer (score 1):

The time is not 5 hours behind, it's exactly the same time. The problem is with the way you print it.

You need to tell C# and Java to use the same time-zone when converting the date to string. One of them is using UTC and the other CDT.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.date automatically corrects for your time zone.  See this question: [How to set time zone of a java.util.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/java-how-to-set-timezone-of-a-java-util-date)

Answer (score 0):

The `ctime` is UTC (Universal Coordinated Time), which is a time standard referenced to Greenwich.  You're expressing your time in Central time.  There's your difference.