# Creating Date object without TimeZone offset all in one line

Tags: java, date, timezone, jasper-reports

I'm trying to populate a `TextField` in JasperReport with the duration of some kind. This field's value is in miliseconds and to make it readable to user, I used Java's Date class ans SimpleDateFormat class to convert it to `hh:mm:ss` format like this:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(new Date($F{milisec}.longValue()))
```

The `$F{milisec}` is Double so I had to convert it to long. Anyway, The problem is that the output of this expression has my local timezone added to it. So if the field's value is `10000.0`, then the output would be `01:30:10` (assuming my machine's TimeZone is set to +1:30). I searched how to set the TimeZone, and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/java-how-to-set-timezone-of-a-java-util-date):

```
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = isoFormat.parse("2010-05-23T09:01:02");
```

The thing is that I'm going to use my code as a JasperReport expression and as far as I know, I'm not allowed to use multiple lines in there. So how can I set the TimeZone of a date in java all in one line so it is considered one expression?

Comment: This isn't what a `Date` is designed for. What you have done is created a timestamp that is X mills after the epoch. This is **not** a duration. Surprisingly enough, until Java 8 comes out, Java has no way to represent a duration. Let alone to format one. You will either need to do this manually or use a library (like the excellent [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)).

Comment: Putting aside the TimeZone problem, the rest is working perfectly. Are you saying that what I want can not be done in one line?

Comment: Yes. This will not work as you are printing out the time of a timestamp **not** a duration expressed in hours and minutes. You are actually calculating the a timestamp that is some millis after Thursday, 1 January 1970 at 00:00:00.000; this means that if your duration is more than 24 hours you will get 2 January 1970 at some point - your time will be "reset". This will not work.

Comment: I'm fully aware of that, and it's not a problem in my case. It would be great if you guide me how to get what I want using the named classes. Thanks.

Comment: Or if you are to advise some new class, I need it to be included in Java by default. I'm limited to use no external libraries.

Comment: I'm saying that Java has **no support** of durations of any kind (beside time, which is a duration since the epoch). You cannot do what you want using the JDK classes. If you cannot use external resources you will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: I know that Java does not support duration, but the solution given here solves my problem perfectly if I can set the TimeZone to GMT. My case is guaranteed never to exceed 24 hours so if I can set the TimeZone in the same line as the rest of code, I'm all done.

Comment: In addition, even my own code is considered an external library.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY builtin parameter, which would give you a default implementation of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.FormatFactory.

With that you can do something like $P{REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY}.createDateFormat("hh:mm:ss", $P{REPORT_LOCALE}, TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")).format(new Date($F{milisec}.longValue()))

You could also store the $P{REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY}.createDateFormat(..) result in a parameter or variable so that you don't create a new object on each record.