# Date() command in java take est time why?My system shows utc and i also want utc time?

Tags: java

Here this last_checked_datetime is my date stored in database which is in utc format,

```
 Timestamp ts1=rs9.getTimestamp("last_checked_datetime");
 java.sql.Date last_chk=new java.sql.Date(ts1.getTime());
 java.util.Date time=new java.util.Date(last_chk.getTime());
 java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
 String old_time=sdf.format(time);
```

When I call this Date() it was print EST time

```
 String new_time=sdf.format(new Date());
 Date date1 = sdf.parse(old_time);
 Date date2 = sdf.parse(new_time);
```

I want difference of these two but date1 take utc time and date2 take est time which cause a barrier in my code?
Please suggest

Comment: Maybe look into `GregorianCalendar` to allow for timezone control.

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date

Comment: but same code i use on other machine , and it works correctly. Is there any machine related problem or i have to change in a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a default time zone as such-

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `org.joda.time.DateTime`

This allows you to control what timezone you want the date to be in.

For example:

```
DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate()
```

Comment: but same code i use on other machine , and it works correctly. Is there any machine related problem or i have to change in a code?

Comment: By default, the timezone comes from the `user.timezone` system property, so if these are different on your two machines, this would explain why there is a difference between your results.

Comment: If my answer has helped you solve your problem, it is general practise on stack overflow to accept the answer by pressing the green tick next to it :)

Comment: could you please tell me how can i see this timezone of my system? because when i use date command in my both machine, it shows same date in utc.

Comment: Write a quick test containing the following: 

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.timezone"));`

This will show you the current timezone of your jvm

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
//change the timezone
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```