# How to set fastTime of a java.util.Date?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

This is related to [How to set time zone of a java.util.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date)

I am trying to set in the eclipse debugger the value of

```
private transient long fastTime;
```

in a `java.util.Date`.

I want to set the date to sometime on 01/01/2010 which based on http://www.epochconverter.com is the value (in milliseconds) `1262362075000`.

This field is supposed to be of `long` type but when I try to set this field (`fastTime`) I am told by eclipse that this value is too large for the field.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try:

fastTime = 1262362075000L;

Comment: If you use just a number, java try to cast to int. You have to explicitly say it's a long and not a int adding L in the end of the number.

Comment: This also worked for me while debugging in IntelliJ, thank a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Eclipse Debugger, but what is interesting here is that the error message implies that Eclipse is expecting an input of `type int`. Have you tried to input a smaller number in the range of `int`? Either for some reason Eclipse assumes that `fastTime` is `int`, or the input handling of Eclipse just allows `int` (or it can be adjusted somewhere, so that `long` is allowed, too).

Comment: On second thought, I think the `int` refers to the value I tried to assign, not to the variable I was trying to assign to (`fastTime`).