# Reading system time in CST time zone using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to read the system date in CST time zone using Java. I tried the below code but whenever I use `formatter.parse()` it is returning time in EST time zone.

```
private Date getTodayInCST() {
    Calendar currentdate = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    TimeZone obj = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");
    formatter.setTimeZone(obj);

    String today = formatter.format(currentdate.getTime());
    try {
        return formatter.parse(today);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: A Date does not have time zone information so what you are trying to do is not possible. You can *print* a Date with a given time zone setting though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set time zone of a java.util.Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date)

Comment: It may not be returning the date in EST.  We are now currently in C***D***T, in which times are 1 hour later than they are in CST. If the time you are reading is in CDT, the output would look like EST to you.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.util.Date` objects do not contain any timezone information by themselves - you cannot set the timezone on a Date object. The only thing that a Date object contains is a number of milliseconds since the "epoch" - 1 January 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

If you want to set timezone try it this way

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" )
)
```

## Details

> I am trying to read the system date in CST time zone

By “CST”, do you mean *Central Standard Time* in North America, or *China Standard Time*?

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique as seen above with `CST`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy. Supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Get the current moment in UTC. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

> 2018-02-26T05:45:24.213610Z

Adjust into another time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-02-25T23:45:24.213610-06:00[America/Chicago]

The above strings are in standard ISO 8601 format. The `ZonedDateTime` class extends that standard wisely to append the name of the zone in square brackets.

If you want to generate String objects in other formats, use `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

If want to the code to provide the current time considering the daylight saving adjustment  from CST to CDT or vice versa ,you can use the 
"CST6CDT" timezone. in place of "CST" in SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat cstCdtFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
cstCdtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST6CDT"));
System.out.println(cstCdtFormat.format(new Date()));
```