# How to query objects in Azure Cosmos DB with datetime field

Tags: c#, .net, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have a requirement to filter the objects of Azure Cosmos DB using datetime field. The structure of the object is as follows.

```
{
    "nodeId": 3,
    "nodeName": "HAVC",
    "assetId": 2,
    "assetName": "Chiller_02",
    "assetMeasurementId": 22,
    "assetMeasurementName": "CHL01_WATER_ENTER_TEMP",
    "streamId": 0,
    "streamName": null,
    "deviceId": 4,
    "deviceTagId": 48,
    "rawTelemetryData": 49,
    "observationPropertyId": 1,
    "isActive": false,
    "enqueueDatetime": "2019-05-31T07:17:45",
    "receivedDatetime": "2019-06-03T18:51:16.6684284",
    "id": "1e9fe261-5e73-4a64-8921-817a6c601ea0",
    "_rid": "PfsxALhViWYWAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/PfsxAA==/colls/PfsxALhViWY=/docs/PfsxALhViWYWAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"0000f80f-0000-1800-0000-5cf51e930000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1559568019
}
```

In this, we need to query the data using 'receivedDatetime' field and we need data between '18:51' to '18:57'

In C#, we use a syntax similar to LINQ

```
var queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<TestDto>(
        UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
        new { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
    .Where(x => x.receivedDatetime >= DateTime.Parse(startDate))
    .Where(x => x.receivedDatetime <= DateTime.Parse(endDate))
    .OrderBy(x => x.receivedDatetime)
    .AsDocumentQuery();
```

But we were unable to receive the data as expected. Appreciate if you can kindly provide some support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do efficient range queries on a numeric field in Cosmosdb you have to define a Range Index on the path containing your numeric field when you create the Container.

CosmosDB does not support querying **[`DateTime`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6455739-support-date-datatype-and-querying)**. You can have a look on the blog here to understand [`more`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-dates-in-azure-documentdb-4/)

Comment: Looks like that has been fixed according to this page https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/cosmos-db/sql/working-with-dates

Answer (score 1):

You can check this -[DateTime, the Epoch and DocumentDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973710/datetime-the-epoch-and-documentdb) You have to store receivedDatetime in ISO-8601 date/time format