# Convert new Date() to different timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, timezone

If i have:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));

String dateStr = dateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(dateStr);
```

The output will be: 2014-09-30 14:19:17 when my local time is 2014-09-30 16:19:17

I need to get **Date** type in specific timezone and not **String** Type!

My question is , how can i get **new Date()** on **"Europe/London"** timezone,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set time zone of a java.util.Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date)

Comment: new date() is deprecated btw , use Calendar

Comment: `Date` not contains timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> My question is, how can i get `new Date()` on "Europe/London" timezone

You can't. The `java.util.Date` class represents an *instant* in time. It is not aligned to any local time zone.

Internally, it tracks the number of milliseconds since Midnight, January 1st, 1970 UTC.  A local time zone might be applied when you *use* it, but there is no time zone setting contained within the `Date` class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar , for example :

```
TimeZone timeZone= TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
```

also , the good thing about dates is that they arent dependant of TimeZone , its just time in millis since epoch (some time a while back) . The way you are using it now is actually the right solution .

Comment: The `Date` class itself is not deprecated, just some of its methods, but otherwise you're right.

Comment: yeah i said new Date() in beginning . Sorry about the confusion

Comment: new Date() is _not_ deprecated, though other Date constructors are.

Comment: tbh there is no right way to say it but , its just that Date package was messed up before Calendar , point taken tho ;)