# Calender class and changed TimeZone conflicts

Tags: java, date, calendar

I would like to get the **date format** as **yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00** and **different TimeZone**  as an output. But here i am getting the default Time Zone in the output to calendar date.

```
Code part as:-
Calendar cal =  Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.NOVEMBER);
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 18);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 20);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
System.out.println("DateTime : " +  cal.getTime()+ " \n Zone :: "+ calFrom.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
```

The output as:

```
DateTime : Wed Nov 19 05:30:00 IST 2014 
Zone :: Greenwich Mean Time
```

Here, i set the Time zone as **GMT** but in date it shows **IST**  and how it can be converted to 2014-11-19T00:00:00  corrosponding to the changed Time Zone.

Comment: The `Date` object has no relation to the `TimeZone` of the `Calendar` object that created it.

Comment: If you want to format in a specific calendar / time zone, you should use `DateFormat`...

Comment: i have to implement it in an API that takes Calender object but for different Time Zone.

Comment: So how can i get Calender reference for other TimeZones.

Comment: @TarunChaudhary: It's not *at all* clear what you mean - what does "implement it" mean? You already have a calendar in a different time zone, but you're printing out a `Date`, and that *doesn't* have a time zone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set time zone of a java.util.Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date)

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to get the date format as yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00 and different TimeZone as an output.

Then you need to be using a `DateFormat` of some description, e.g. `SimpleDateFormat`. In particular, a `DateFormat` knows about:

- The format
- The locale to use for things like month names
- The time zone
- The calendar system

`Date` - which is what `Calendar.getTime()` returns - doesn't know about *any* of that. It just represents a point in time, which can be represented in many different ways.

You probably want something like:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC");
Calendar cal =  Calendar.getInstance(zone);
cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
cal.set(2014, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 18, 20, 0, 0); // Why 20 if you want an hour of 0?

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(zone);

String text = format.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: there is a didifference of 6 Hours and 30 minutes in IST and GMT. if i put 
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30); then only i am getting 00:00:00.

Comment: @TarunChaudhary: No, IST is UTC+05:30. (GMT and UTC are equivalent, for the purposes of this discussion - but it's generally better to talk about UTC to avoid confusing things with the UK time zone, which observes GMT for half the year.)

Comment: @TarunChaudhary: What do you mean by that? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve *and* what you're actually seeing... along with the problem of being 1 hour out in your understanding of IST.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = LocalDate.of(2014,Month.NOVEMBER, 18)
                                        .atTime(LocalTime.of(20, 0))
                                        .atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(zdtUtc);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-11-18T20:00Z[Etc/UTC]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/HENi26)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Explanation of the problem you are facing:

A `java.util.Date` object simply represents an instant on the timeline — a wrapper around the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). Since it does not hold any timezone information, its **[`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--)** function applies the JVM's timezone to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format and timezone, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.

```
Date date = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
String strDateNewYork = sdf.format(date);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
String strDateUtc = sdf.format(date);
```

A valuable comment from Ole V.V.:

> If we cannot avoid getting an old-fashioned `Calendar` object, by all
> likelihood it’s really a `GregorianCalendar`, and we can convert it to
> `ZonedDateTime` simply by using `((GregorianCalendar) cal).toZonedDateTime()`. Then we’re set.

Another one:

> Or if using a backport: `DateTimeUtils.toZonedDateTime(cal)`.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: This is the good answer. If we cannot avoid getting an old-fashioned `Calendar` object, by all likelyhood it’s really a `GregorianCalendar`, and we can convert it to `ZonedDateTime` simply by using `((GregorianCalendar) cal).toZonedDateTime()`. Then we’re set.