# Convert date string with timezone to timestamp

Tags: php, date, timezone

I receive dates in the following format `2015-01-09T20:46:00+0100` and need to convert it in timestamp.
Unfortunately, strtotime function is ignoring the timezone component :

```
print strtotime('2015-01-09T20:46:00+0100') . "\n";
print strtotime('2015-01-09T20:46:00');

//result is the same with or without timezone:
//1420832760
//1420832760
```

What is the right way to solve this issue ?

Comment: if its related to java hope this might help
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date>

Comment: you can probably do something like this  `$date = new DateTime('2015-01-09T20:46:00+0100');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fugured out !

> uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that
>   parameter
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

That's why the result is the same setting or not the timezone :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
print strtotime('2015-01-09T20:46:00+0200');
print "\n";
print strtotime('2015-01-09T20:46:00+0100');
print "\n";
print strtotime('2015-01-09T20:46:00');

print "\n\n";

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
print strtotime('2015-01-09T20:46:00+0100');
print "\n";
print strtotime('2015-01-09T20:46:00');
```

output:

```
1420829160
1420832760
1420832760

1420832760
1420836360
```

Demo: https://eval.in/241781

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

DateTime handles this correctly:

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-01-09T20:46:00+0100');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
echo "\n";
$date = new DateTime('2015-01-09T20:46:00');
echo $date->getTimestamp();

1420832760
1420836360
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/241751)

Comment: lol, why didn't this worked on my localhost? I first though also that `DateTime` works, but on my XAMPP localhost server it doesn't works, do you have a idea?

Comment: Honestly, I don't. Best guess is a php version bug. What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: My PHP version is: `5.5.6`, i tried it on `ideone.com` and `eval.in` and it worked, now i tired it on: `3v4l.org` and it didn't worked look here: http://3v4l.org/cYnDG , it seems to be really strange

Comment: I think this shouldn't work! Because take a look into the manual->parameters->notes and read the note! http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: Same for me. DateTime method and strtotime both worked on eval.in but not on my local WAMP (php 5.5.8)

Comment: @Rizier123 my interpretation of the note is that the timezone in the input string is used instead of the $timezone param