# Convert UTC time in long value to GMT time in Android

Tags: android, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I have UTC time in long value = 1555415100000L.
Now I want to convert to local time in different time zone.

example:

1555415100000L = 2019/04/16 18:45 (GMT+7)

1555415100000L = 2019/04/16 14:45 (GMT+3)
...

Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: The long value are the time represented in milliseconds. here is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292032/converting-from-milliseconds-to-utc-time-in-java

Comment: you can create a `Date` object out of that and then you can use `Calendar` object in Android with a `Locale` of your choosing, after which you can use `DateFormat` to properly display it on the screen. A bit of research using these keywords will help.

Comment: @acarlstein: your solution doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this method. This method returns specific GMT as formatted String. You should give time in millisecond and GMT value to this method.

```
private String getSpecificGmtDate(long timeMillis, int gmt) {
    long time = timeMillis + (gmt * 1000 * 60 * 60);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    return (sdf.format(new Date(time)) + " (GMT " + gmt + ")");
}
```

output:

```
System.out.println(getSpecificGmtDate(1555415100000L, 0));
16/04/2019 11:45 (GMT 0)
System.out.println(getSpecificGmtDate(1555415100000L, 3));
16/04/2019 14:45 (GMT 3)
System.out.println(getSpecificGmtDate(1555415100000L, -3));
16/04/2019 08:45 (GMT -3)
```

Comment: How about time zone: GMT+5:30

Comment: you can add easily. Its basic programming logic.     

`private String getSpecificGmtDate(long timeMillis, int gmtHour, int gmtMin) {
        if(gmtMin==0){gmtMin=60;}
        long time = timeMillis + (gmtHour * 1000 * 60 * gmtMin); ....`