# Convert date to Eastern Time - Get Date object as output

Tags: java, date, timezone, date-conversion, java.util.date

I've seen many examples of converting date from one time zone to another. But all of them has output as a String. I want a date object as output.

The methods I've tried -

**Approach 1**

```
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z");
dateTimeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
Date date = new Date();

System.out.println(dateTimeFormat.format(date)); // this print IST Timezone

DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z");
timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

String estTime = timeFormat.format(date);
try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(estTime);
    System.out.println(date);

    } catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(A.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}


System.out.println(timeFormat.format(date));
```

**Approach 2**

```
private static Date shiftTimeZone(Date date, TimeZone sourceTimeZone, TimeZone targetTimeZone) {
        System.out.println(sourceTimeZone.toString());
        System.out.println(targetTimeZone.toString());
        Calendar sourceCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        sourceCalendar.setTime(date);
        sourceCalendar.setTimeZone(sourceTimeZone);

        Calendar targetCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (int field : new int[]{Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.MILLISECOND}) {
            targetCalendar.set(field, sourceCalendar.get(field));
        }
        targetCalendar.setTimeZone(targetTimeZone);

        return targetCalendar.getTime();
    }
```

Approach 1  gives me result as a String.

```
03/22/2018 10:16:57 AM EDT <- instanceOf String
```

Approach 2 gives me correct date and time of Eastern Time time zone, but the Date has the time zone of IST.

```
Thu Mar 22 10:16:57 IST 2018 <- instanceof Date
```

Can anyone please help me to obtain a Date object with Eastern Time TimeZone.

**Update -** My ultimate goal is to get Unix Timestamp of the current Eastern Time.

Comment: `Date` object has no internal timezone (it's a number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 midnight UTC). Want something else.

Comment: For more information: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This particular Date object `Thu Mar 22 10:16:57 IST 2018` has IST mentioned here.. Can't it have EDT or EST there in place of IST?

Comment: Just use `ZonedDateTime` of [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Contrary to the outdated `Date` class this contains a time zone. You want its [`withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set time zone of a java.util.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date). See for example [Jesper’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2892156/5772882).

Comment: @HarshitaSethi *This particular Date object Thu Mar 22 10:16:57 IST 2018 has IST mentioned here.. Can't it have EDT or EST there in place of IST?* No. This particular **computer** you are using has a system timezone of IST. You can change your **computer's** timezone to EST (America/New_York), and then the *default `toString()`* will output EST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()                        // Capture the current moment in UTC, an `Instant` object.
    .atZone(                         // Adjust from UTC into a particular time zone.
        ZoneId.of( “Asia/Kolkata” ) 
    )                                // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
    .withZoneSameInstant(            // Adjust into yet another time zone. All three are the same moment but vowed using different wall-clock times. 
        ZoneId.of( “Africa/Tunis” ) 
    )                                // Returns another `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

Or…

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( “Asia/Kolkata” )
).withZoneSameInstant(
    ZoneId.of( “Africa/Tunis” )
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Firstly, stop using the legacy date-time classes. They are an awful wretched mess. Supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

- `Date` is replaced by `Instant`.
- `Calendar` is replaced by `ZonedDateTime`
- `SimpleDateFormat` is replaced by `DateTimeFormatter`.

## Deceived by `Date::toString`

Secondly, understand that `Date` has a horribly confusing feature of dynamically applying your JVM’s current default time zone while generating a String. **`Date` always represents a moment in UTC.** The `toString` method creates a false illusion of `Date` carrying  a time zone, when actually its value is in UTC. While well-intentioned by the class designers, this was a disastrous decision, causing no end of confusion amongst countless programmers for decades now.

Even worse: There actually *is* a time zone buried in a `Date`, but is irrelevant to this discussion. Confusing? Yes; as I said, an awful wretched mess of bad design.

## `Instant`

The `Instant` class replacing `Date` is much clearer. An `Instant` represents a moment, a point on the timeline, always in UTC, with a resolution of nanoseconds.

Use `Instant` to capture the current moment in UTC. The JVM’s current default time zone is irrelevant. The host OS’ assigned time zone is irrelevant.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Unlike `Date::toString`, the `Instant::toString` method tells the truth. A `Instant` is always in UTC, so `toString` always reports UTC. A String is generated in standard ISO 8601 format. The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means UTC.

> instant.toString(): 2018-01-23T12:34:56.123456789Z

About capturing the current moment… In Java 8, the current moment was *captured* in milliseconds even though the java.time classes can *represent* nanoseconds. In Java 9 and later, a new implementation of `Clock` provides for capturing the current moment in finer granularity. In Java 9.0.4 on macOS Sierra, I see microseconds. The hardware clocks on conventional computers nowadays cannot capture the current moment with accuracy beyond microseconds.

## `ZonedDateTime`

To view that same moment through the lens of a wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, assign that region’s time zone. Applying a `ZoneId` to an `Instant` produces a `ZonedDateTime`. Conceptually:

> ZonedDateTime = ( Instant + ZoneId )

In code:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “Pacific/Auckland” ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;   // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

Adjusting to another time zone is easy. You can start with the `Instant` again.

```
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( “Asia/Kolkata” ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zKolkata ) ;
```

Or you can adjust the `ZonedDateTime` object. The *java.time* classes use immutable objects. So rather than “mutate” (alter) the original object, the adjustment produces a new distinct object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zKolkata ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

You can skip the use of the `Instant`. I do not recommend doing so. Programmers should be doing their thinking, debugging, logging, exchanging of data, and much of their business logic in UTC. So `Instant` should be your go-to class whenever you start any work with date-time values.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ) ;
```

The `ZonedDateTime::toString` method wisely extends the ISO 8601 standard by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdtNewYork.toString() ;
```

> 2018-01-23T07:34:56.123456789-05:00[America/New_York]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Interesting.  Please elaborate or point link to detail with "Even worse: There actually is a time zone buried in a Date".  :)

Comment: @MattJohnson Look at [source code for `java.util.Date`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Date.java) and search for the word `zone`. You will find 73 matches. You may also want to explore the `sun.util.calendar.*` classes used by that implementation.

Comment: Does Instant and ZonedDateTime has methods to convert to Unix Timestamp also?