# Possible bug in Java 8 SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, java-8, simpledateformat

Java 8 here, I have the following code:

```
public class PossibleBug {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PossibleBug().run();
  }

  public void run() {

    buildDate("20181205");

  }

  public Date buildDate(final String yyyyMmDd) throws ParseException {
    TimeZone expectedTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    sdf.setTimeZone(expectedTz);

    TimeZone actualTz = sdf.getTimeZone();

    Date answer = sdf.parse(yyyyMmDd);
    return answer;
  }

}
```

So pretty basic stuff:

1. create a `SimpleDateFormat` and set its timezone to EST
2. Use the SDF to parse a date string
3. Result *should* be a date in EST as well

However at runtime, look at the debugger results:

[image]

**How is this possible?!?!** `sdf.parse(yyyyMmDd)` is returning a date formatted in GMT. Is there something I'm missing on my end or is this a bug in `SimpleDateFormat`?

I am able to invoke `buildDate` and run it from inside a different class and it seems to work fine:

[image]

Comment: You've explicitly tagged with [java-8], so *don't* use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Use classes from `java.time`.

Comment: This works fine for me. Output is `Wed Dec 05 00:00:00 EST 2018`. So something is wrong with your environment.

Comment: 05.12.2018 00:00 interpreted as being in America/New_York is 05:00 in GMT as it is printed in your example.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZoneId`, `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date` stores no timezone. It's essentially just a wrapper around a `long`, storing millis after epoch.

When you print it (or when your debugger invokes the `toString()` method to get a string representation to display), your JVM's default timezone is used, irrespective of how it was created.

`Date`, despite the name, doesn't model a date: it's an *instant* in time.

Given that your input is `"20181205"`, don't use `Date`: use classes from `java.time` like `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: Thanks @Andy Turner (+1) for reasons outside the scope of this question, I *must* use `Date`. But it sounds like you're saying that the `answer` is timezone-less, and that the reason why I'm seeing GMT in the printed output is because IDEA is just selecting my JVM's default TZ?

Comment: Yes. <padding>.

Comment: OK thanks, however if I simply instantiate a `PossibleBug` instance from inside _another_ class, and then run its `buildDate(...)` method with the same exact input arg string (`"20181205"`), it seems to work perfectly. Any chance you can explain why there would be a difference in the print/debugger output in the 2nd screenshot?

Comment: Are you setting the default timezone in that code?

Comment: No :-/ thats what is so weird about this...

Comment: Also @Andy Turner I think you may have a wrong notion about Java `Date`s being timezone-less. Check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2891412/5235665), seems to indicate the pre-Java 8 `Date`s can absolutely have timezones

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup that answer does the same as your question’s code, it uses a timezone when parsing the date. At no point does it indicate that the resulting `Date` object has a timezone. So in your case, your debugger formats the date differently. That might be strange, but entirely irrelevant for your application.

Comment: Thanks @Holger (+1) but if Dates can't hold a timezone, then whats the point of setting the timezone in the SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: You are converting a date string to a `Date` object which is actually an instant. Likewise, when you are formatting this instant called `Date` to an actual date/time string, again a timezone will be used. As you've seen yourself, it makes a difference. The same instant becomes `Wed Dec 05 00:00:00` when formatting to EST but `Wed Dec 05 05:00:00` when formatting to GMT.

Comment: Right, so by setting the timezone on the SimpleDateFormat, I should be telling it to **always** format the instant/Date with the EST timezone. So why is it ignoring EST in one class (and instead using GMT) and honoring the `setTimeZone(...)` call in another?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup have a look at what `TimeZone.getDefault()` is in both places. *You* might not be setting it, but maybe something else is (such is the problem with mutable global state).

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [the Java-Doc for `SimpleDateFormat.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-), you can see that the TimeZone might be overwritten:

> The `TimeZone` value may be overwritten, depending on the given pattern and the time zone value in `text`. Any `TimeZone` value that has previously been set by a call to `setTimeZone` may need to be restored for further operations.

Comment: thanks for the advise!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) says: "This parsing operation uses the calendar to produce a Date. All of the calendar's date-time fields are cleared before parsing, and the calendar's default values of the date-time fields are used for any missing date-time information. For example, the year value of the parsed Date is 1970 with GregorianCalendar if no year value is given from the parsing operation. *The TimeZone value may be overwritten, depending on the given pattern and the time zone value in text.* Any TimeZone value that has previously been set by a call to setTimeZone may need to be restored for further operations."

In short, `SimpleDateFormat` is a formatter/parser, not a utility for performing time zone conversions. If there's no TZ in the string you are parsing, you get the default value from `Calendar`.

Consider what would happen if you called `setTimeZone,` then parsed a string that actually contained a time zone itself? What would you expect to happen?

Also, note that `Date` doesn't contain a time zone. It's specifically defined as being the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00 UTC. Library functions apply a time zone when needed (like when converting to a `String`) and if you don't specify one, you'll get the default time zone. You see GMT because your default time zone is GMT or because your IDE always displays `Date` objects in GMT, and the person who said he got EST must have is default time zone set to EST.

In your case, you're parsing a string that does not contain a time zone at all. In fact, it doesn't even contain a time. Using `Date` to handle, uh, dates (I realize this is confusing, I mean dates without times), is likely to lead to mistakes, especially when your default time zone isn't UTC/GMT. I recommend using `LocalDate` and the `LocalDate.parse` method.