# Timezone issue in Spring Boot JPA application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, timezone

I am facing date time issue in my spring boot jpa application.

For example, In my database I have one column `created_on` which contains `2019-07-11 09:30:00` date.
When I fetch this record through JPA it converts to UTC.
For example it converts `2019-07-11 09:30:00` into `2019-07-11 05:00:00`.

My System time is in IST and date is saved in database in IST as well.

I am using mysql database.

In my Enitity

```
private Date createdOn;
```

Database column:

```
created_on timestamp
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class EntityTypeService {
  @Autowired
  private IEntityTypeRepository entityTypeRepository;

  public EntityType findById(Long id) {
    EntityType entityType = entityTypeRepository.findById(id).orElse(new EntityType());
    System.out.println(entityType.getCreatedOn());
    return entityType;
  }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface IEntityTypeRepository extends CrudRepository<EntityType, Long> {
}
```

Date in database is `2019-07-11 09:30:00`

But when I print it on service `System.out.println(entityType.getCreatedOn());` it gives me `2019-07-11 05:00:00`.

This is generic issue in my whole application.

Comment: And the problem is? Please show a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could you add code how you save and read your date object? Do you use LocalDateTime for both?

Comment: @Luuk this is generic issue in my whole application that's why i have not attached any code previously. After you suggestion added code. Please let me know anything need.

Comment: @Milgo I have date already available in database which is correct by when i fetch it using `findById` method of `CrudRepository` it gives me converted date to UTC. Attached code for reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After so much research I found the solution.

Actually issue was because of

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

this property which I have set in my `appication.properties`.

When I removed this property everything works fine at the backend. Backend showing the perfect time which is available in database.

But now when response comes to frontend, at that time my date gets converted to UTC.

Like backend it's showing  `2020-06-03 18:56:14.0` and when it comes to front end it converts to `2020-06-02T13:26:14.000+0000`.

Which is also an issue for me.

So after some more research I found that `Jackson` by default converts all date to UTC when object send to frontend.

The solution to this problem is

```
spring.jackson.time-zone=IST
```

My Database and System timezone is IST so I have set IST to jackson timezone too which solves the problem.

Hope this answer may help someone.

Comment: Vivek Jain, you don't have to remove the jpa property, instead add `serverTimezone` query parameter. See my answer above and as well as @Eklavya answer.

Answer (score 4):

When working on JPA + Spring Boot for a backend application, make sure to use same TimeZone through out server configuration. For example, to use UTC do as below:

- On server OS level: `sudo timedatectl set-timezone UTC` (for example on Cent OS)
- On MySQL / Database server in `my.cnf` file (optional)
- Spring config: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC`
- MySQL URL query parameters `spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/my_db_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`
- And if you are using Jackson JSON framework you can automatically parse `DateTime` value to String format using `@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")` on the entity property / field.
- Application entry point `@SpringBootApplication`

`@PostConstruct public void init(){ TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); }`

This should cover most of the implementation challenges while work on Dates and Timestamps. Hope that it helps.

Comment: Sir, the only thing that helped in my case (Sping + MySQL 8) is setting context-wide TimeZone in the configuration class; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set timezone for in database connection using `serverTimezone` eg:`Asia/Kolkata` and use `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`

```
spring.datasource.url= = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/db_name?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Kolkata
```

And don't use legacy class `Date` rather use modern class `LocalDateTime`

Comment: Tried this but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure your timezone in your application are same as application ? And don't use legacy class Date rather use LocalDateTime

Comment: yes my system time and mysql time is same. also i have printed `System.out.println(new Date());` which gives me perfect time as my system has.

Comment: Use `LocalDateTime` class `Date`  is legacy class with troublesome behavior

Comment: I have given as example. But currently i am using native query in JPA which returns me Map<String, Object> there also date gets converted.

Comment: If you use in entity `LocalDateTime` for column it will return `LocalDateTime` when you are doing native query also

Comment: Suppose I don't want to convert result into Entity. I just want to return `Map<String, Object>` as a result which was returning from JPA NativeQuery then?

Comment: That's different problem I think, here from object you want to cast the data if I properly understand. And get as Object then cast is not a good way I think. And you current problem in post will be solved using this. And cast as LocalDateTime should work I think but not tested

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using Date for timestamps in time zones because it is not designed to handle these in a good way.

You could try to print the date object with a [formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2891412/3275441) or use LocalDateTime (or ZonedDateTime if time zones are important to you) instead.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue. Because if i use native query in JPA which returns me Map<String, Object> there also date gets converted.

Answer (score 0):

You may try putting `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")` on `createdOn` setter.