# Change time zone of exesting date in Java

Tags: java, timezone

I want to change the time zone of given date. I use this code, but i dont have the good result.
My input is "2020-06-16 14:00:00" time in Europe/Paris, and I wnat to change it to UTC, that means I want to get "2020-06-16 12:00:00", but I get initial result "2020-06-16 14:00:00".

```
try {
    // Calendar calParis = Calendar.getInstance();
    String heure = "1400";
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2020-06-16");

    String hour = heure.substring(0, heure.length() - 2);
    String minute = heure.substring(heure.length() - 2);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String datenew = "2020-06-16" + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":00";
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDatenew = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date thisDate = sdfDatenew.parse(datenew);
    cal.setTime(thisDate);

    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/UTC"));
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String dateISO = null;
    dateISO = sdfDate.format(cal.getTime());

    System.out.println("Time in ISO: " + dateISO);

} catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

Comment: I found an answer to your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set time zone of a java.util.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date)

Comment: i test the code

SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = isoFormat.parse("2010-05-23T09:01:02");

but it dose not work

Comment: it should me return the 2010-05-23T07:01:02 that means hours - 2

Comment: Can you use `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId`? then the solution could be simple.

Comment: ... or `OffsetDateTime` and `ZoneOffset.UTC`? That means using `java.time` instead of `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar` and `TimeZone`. All of those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate`, `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:
This way you can get your dates and time in Java-7 format.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String heure = "1400";
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2020-06-16");
        String hour = heure.substring(0, heure.length() - 2);
        String minute = heure.substring(heure.length() - 2);
        String datenew = "2020-06-16" + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":00";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date thisDate = sdf.parse(datenew);
        calendar.setTime(thisDate);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PDT"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime())); // prints 2020-06-16 12:00:00
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime())); // prints 2020-06-16 14:00:00
    }
```

Comment: These date-time classes are *terrible*, avoid them. For Java 8 and later, use the built-in *java.time* classes. For Java 6 & 7, use the back-port of *java.time*, *ThreeTen-Backport* library.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDateTime
.parse( 
    "2020-06-16 14:00:00"
    .replace( " " , "T" ) 
)
.atZone(
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" )
)
.toInstant()
.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" )
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/kusTFI).

> 2020-06-16 12:00:00

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses *java.time* classes.

Your input string lacks a time zone or offset. So parse as a `LocalDateTime` object.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2020-06-16 14:00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ) ;
```

You say with certainty that this string represents a moment as seen in Paris France time zone.

```
ZoneId zParis = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zParis ) ;
```

Adjust from there to your target time zone. You happen to want UTC, so just extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>, released in March 2014 as part of Java SE 8 standard library.

The [answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67925155/10819573) is correct but I would not use `String` replacement when `DateTimeFormatter` is capable enough to address this and much more.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "2020-06-16 14:00:00";
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, dtfInput);
        ZonedDateTime zdtParis = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = zdtParis.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        // Default format
        System.out.println(zdtUtc);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String output = dtfOutput.format(zdtUtc);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-16T12:00Z[Etc/UTC]
2020-06-16 12:00:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/9AMfWj)

**All in a single statement:**

```
System.out.println(
        LocalDateTime
        .parse("2020-06-16 14:00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH))
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"))
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"))
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH))
);
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/BfRXnF)

**Some important notes:**

1. You can use a single pattern, `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` for both of your input and output strings but I prefer using `u-M-d H:m:s` for parsing because `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` will fail if you have a year in two digits, a month in single digit, a day-of-month in single digit etc. For parsing, a single `u` can cater to both, two-digit and four-digit year representation. Similarly, a single `M` can cater to both one-digit and two-digit month. Similar is the case with other symbols.
2. Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>