# Get a LocalDateTime object from a given string?

Tags: java, java-time, localdatetime

```
"2021-09-17 11:48:06 UTC"
```

I want to parse the following string and create a `LocalDateTime` object or an `Instant`

I know you can write something like this

```
String dateTime = "2021-09-17 11:48:06 UTC";
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

How do I deal with the `UTC` part in the string?

Comment: No. I know how to format strings like how they are doing it in the post you referred me to.  I want to know how do I deal with that `UTC` part?

Comment: "2021-09-17 11:48:06 UTC" isn't a local date time: it's a date time, because it has a time zone. Parse it to a DateTime, then use `toLocalDateTime()`.

Comment: Oh ok, that's different. Thanks you for edit. And yes, such as says by Andy, you have to use global datetime instead of local

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22126586/1357094

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"2021-09-17 11:48:06 UTC" isn't a local date time: it's a date time, because it has a time zone. And because your time has a time zone, it doesn't match your pattern, which doesn't.

If your time strings always end with exactly "UTC", you can make that a literal in the pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'");
```

If you need to handle other time zones than UTC, you can use `z`:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
```

but note that this is for parsing a zoned date time; from that, you can extract the local date time:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
LocalDateTime ldt =z dt.toLocalDateTime();
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Never hardcode the standard timezone text like `UTC`, `GMT` etc.

Never hardcode the standard timezone text like `UTC`, `GMT` etc. which `DateTimeFormatter` is already capable of handling in the best way.

Parse the given Date-Time string using the pattern, `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV` into a `TemporalAccessor` from which you can get the `Instant` as well as the `LocalDateTime`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2021-09-17 11:48:06 UTC";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV", Locale.ENGLISH);
        TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = dtf.parse(strDateTime);

        Instant instant = Instant.from(temporalAccessor);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.from(temporalAccessor);

        System.out.println(instant);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-09-17T11:48:06Z
2021-09-17T11:48:06
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/secS1r)

#### Alternatively:

Parse the given Date-Time string using the pattern, `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV` into a `ZonedDateTime` from which you can get the `Instant` as well as the `LocalDateTime`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2021-09-17 11:48:06 UTC";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV", Locale.ENGLISH);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        Instant instant = Instant.from(zdt);
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();

        System.out.println(zdt);
        System.out.println(instant);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-09-17T11:48:06Z[UTC]
2021-09-17T11:48:06Z
2021-09-17T11:48:06
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/TDhBJq)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: If I ever have a question about a datetime, you are the specialist :-)

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for pointing out the requirement for `Instant`. I have updated the answer to meet that requirement as well.

Comment: ++ though I would make `ZonedDateTime` solution top most