# How to obtain UTC format with +0000 in Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, utc

I want to change the date format from `"20230523154325"` to `2023-05-23T15:43:25+0000"`.
And I have this piece of code, but unfortunately the result is this: `"2023-05-23T15:43:25+0300"`.
So I don't want to have `+0300`, I want to have `+0000` at the end. So, it should be exactly the same for this part `2023-05-23T15:43:25`, but instead of `+0300` should be `+0000`. It's important to have this `+0000` at the end. Any feedback will be appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String oldDate = "20230523154325";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    Date newDateFormat = null;

    try {
        newDateFormat = sdf.parse(oldDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    System.out.println("The date is " + sdf1.format(newDateFormat));
}
```

Comment: It's good to state *why* you need it there, because as it stands now, we can't tell which solution would work. For example, with the information you've given, you might as well do substring + "+0000", and it would get the task done as it stands now. With that being said, you can change time zones of SimpleDateFormat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891361/how-to-set-time-zone-of-a-java-util-date . That also means the time itself will change (by the 3 hour difference), so you'd need to account for that somehow.

Comment: First of all I strongly recommend you stop using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` immediately. The former is notoriously troublesome, both poorly designed and bad to work with and both long outdated. Use `LocalDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZoneOffset`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is not a format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to change the date format from 20230523154325 to 2023-05-23T15:43:25+0000

You can do that with `java.time` if you are using Java 8 or higher.

#### Example Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String oldDate = "20230523154325";
    // prepare a parser
    DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss");
    // parse the oldDate with the parser
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(oldDate, parser);
    // print the result (NO OFFSET SO FAR!!!)
    System.out.println(ldt);
    // add an offset (UTC = +00:00 = Z)
    OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // print it
    System.out.println(odt);
    // prepare a formatter for the desired output
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxx");
    // then print the datetime plus offset in the desired format
    System.out.println(odt.format(formatter));
}
```

#### Output

```
2023-05-23T15:43:25
2023-05-23T15:43:25Z
2023-05-23T15:43:25+0000
```

There are prebuilt ones for standard/common formats like `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, which are worth a look. However, you have to create those two `DateTimeFormatter`s *manually* in this case, because none of the prebuilt ones can parse your input format and none of them can produce your desired output.

---

##### Why did your attempt fail to produce the desired result?

Your attempt involves the zone/offset of your machine/jvm, which will even change the offset when the code is executed on another machine with a different zone/offset.

That's why you

- should stop using `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` whenever/wherever you can…
- should switch to `java.time` because you have full control over zone/offset handling

---

#### Compact / Short Version

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String oldDate = "20230523154325";
    DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                                    .ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxx");
    String desiredResult = LocalDateTime.parse(oldDate, parser)
                                        .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                                        .format(formatter);
    System.out.println(desiredResult);
}
```

#### Output

```
2023-05-23T15:43:25+0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use SimpleDateFormat.  SimpleDateFormat instances have a timezone, which causes misleading parsing results like what you have observed.

Given the simplicity of your particular use case, I would forget about date-time parsing entirely, and just use a StringBuilder to insert characters:

```
String oldDate = "20230523154325";
StringBuilder formattedDate = new StringBuilder(oldDate);
formattedDate.append("+0000");
formattedDate.insert(12, ':');
formattedDate.insert(10, ':');
formattedDate.insert(8, 'T');
formattedDate.insert(6, '-');
formattedDate.insert(4, '-');
System.out.println("The date is " + formattedDate);
```

Comment: That ought to work. It’s too hand-held for my taste and doesn’t give us the validation you get for free when using the date-time library (read: java.time).