# How do I programmatically set the time zone in Java?

Tags: java, timezone

I know I can feed VM arguments as follows

```
-Duser.timezone="Australia/Sydney"
```

Is there a programmatic way to do the equivalent? I would like the setting to be applied across the entire virtual machine.

Comment: I found myself in the same problem a while ago, I couldn't make it change in runtime.

Comment: Interesting thread here  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176784/timezone-setdefault-changes-in-jdk6

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`java.util.TimeZone.setDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) can be used to set a default time zone to be returned by `getDefault()`.